# System.currentTimeMillis() returns same timestamp

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timestamp

I need to calculate time between two time. `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns same value everytime when it called in `Thread`.
My code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Other codes..
    start_sec = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    fin = false;
    runThread();
    // Other codes..
}

private void runThread() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (i++ < 61) {
                if (!running) return;
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(!fin){
                                int len = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) - start_sec;
                                Log.d("current time: ",String.valueOf(  Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)));
                                Log.d("difference is: ", String.valueOf(len));
                                if(len < 0 && len > 58){
                                    fin=true;
                                 }
                                timerec.getLayoutParams().width = metrics.widthPixels *(60- len)/60;
                                timerec.requestLayout();
                            }
                            else{
                                end_game();
                                running= true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Here is the logs:

```
...
D/current time:: 1492337024
D/difference is:: 0
D/current time:: 1492337024
D/difference is:: 0
....
```

It returs same "time". What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.round() causes the problem.

```
long len = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - start_sec;
Log.d("current time: ",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000));
Log.d("difference is: ", String.valueOf(len));
```

This code works altought dividing.

Answer (score 0):

take time as long. and don't divide it by 1000. the time difference is fraction of seconds.that's why it is showing the same time as you are rounding it.

Answer (score 0):

the difference between two cycle in a while loop is so much less than a second and when your calculating the difference by seconds (you divide current millisecond with 1000) it makes the same second and the difference is 0 seconds.

try to print difference in milliseconds (without dividing).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Other codes..
    start_sec = System.currentTimeMillis();
    fin = false;
    runThread();
    // Other codes..
}

private void runThread() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (i++ < 61) {
                if (!running) return;
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(!fin){
                                int len = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_sec;
                                Log.d("current time: ",String.valueOf(  System.currentTimeMillis()));
                                Log.d("difference is: ", String.valueOf(len));
                                if(len < 0 && len > 58){
                                    fin=true;
                                 }
                                timerec.getLayoutParams().width = metrics.widthPixels *(60- len)/60;
                                timerec.requestLayout();
                            }
                            else{
                                end_game();
                                running= true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```